# Scala Unicode Syntax

Tags: scala, unicode, intellij-idea, sbt

I know that these two are equivalent in Scala:

```
for {x <- xs} yield x
case Nil => println("foo")
```

Note the Unicode replacement for `<-` and `=>`:

```
for {x ← xs} yield x
case Nil ⇒ println("foo")
```

What is this feature called? I googled various combinations of "Scala Unicode Operators/Symbols" and did not find what I was looking for... What are the full list of equivalent symbols? Where is this documented in the Scala website? How do I use this practically? Through keymappers? How do I easily enable this in my IDE (IntelliJ) e.g. if I type `=>`, I want it to auto-correct it to `⇒` in a .scala file for me. Is there an sbt plugin that does this for me maybe?

Comment: The sbt plugin scalariform can do this, among other formatting things. Note, by the way, that while these are operators, normal identifiers for vals, vars and defs can have names with characters that are not in ASCII-low as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Section 1.1 *Identifiers* of the Scala Language Specification](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/01-lexical-syntax.html#identifiers) calls them *Unicode Operators*:

> The Unicode operators `\u21D2` ‘⇒’ and `\u2190` ‘←’, which have the ASCII equivalents `=>` and `<-`, are also reserved.

Answer (score 0):

We call it `monads`,`kleisli arrows` or simply `arrows`. You should install `Scala` plugin for Intellij to get this conversion. The plugin has unicode arrows support.